# Show Database in table (Android Studio)

Tags: android, mysql

I want to make the entries of a database show up in Rows in an Activity. I have created a Row Class to style the layout of each row.

When I run this code my **while** loop doesn't seem to be working - It only shows the first entry of my database. I'm sure I'm just missing a line of code to create the next row. Could someone please take a look at it and maybe see where I'm going wrong??

```
public class ReviewActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

myname.project20.DatabaseHelper1 Db_Today;
LinearLayout reviewcontainer;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_review);

    Db_Today = new DatabaseHelper1(this);
    reviewcontainer = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.reviewcontainer);


    LayoutInflater layoutInflater =
            (LayoutInflater) getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    final View addView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.db1row, null);
    TextView textViewRowReview = (TextView)addView.findViewById(R.id.textViewRowReview);

    Cursor res = Db_Today.getAllData();


    while (res.moveToNext()) {
        textViewRowReview.setText(
                "Name: " + res.getString(1) + "\n" + "Age: " +
                res.getString(2) + "\n" + "Gender: " + res.getString(3) + "\n\n");
    }

    Button buttonRemove = (Button)addView.findViewById(R.id.button_x);
    buttonRemove.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ((LinearLayout) addView.getParent()).removeView(addView);
        }});

    reviewcontainer.addView(addView);
}
```

db1.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_x"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:text="x"/>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewRowReview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/button_x"/>
```

ReviewActivity.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <TextView android:text="Review and Modify Today's Data Here"
        android:id="@+id/TextViewReview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>


<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/reviewcontainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

and I think this is the only important extract from DatabaseHelper1.java

```
    public Cursor getAllData(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor res = db.rawQuery("select * from " + TABLE_NAME, null);
    return res;
}
```

---

If you need any further information please let me know!! Thank you so much for your help <3

Comment: Your while ... will fill the same TextView multiple times and finally show the data from the last selected row

Comment: _Thanks for your help! I tried changing it to this:_

while (res.moveToNext()) {
        textViewRowReview.setText(
                "Name: " + res.getString(1) + "\n" + "Age: " +
                res.getString(2) + "\n" + "Gender: " + res.getString(3) + "\n\n");
reviewcontainer.addView(addView);
    }

_but it just keeps crashing the app. Is there something I'm missing?_

Comment: aha yes, that was never gonna work. thanks for your fast response!!

Answer (score 0):

I see your error. In this section:

```
TextView textViewRowReview = (TextView)addView.findViewById(R.id.textViewRowReview);

Cursor res = Db_Today.getAllData();


while (res.moveToNext()) {
    textViewRowReview.setText(
```

`textViewRowReview` is only a single `TextView` it will keep getting overwritten with each subsequent row your query returns. You need a `ListView` instead.

How you populate this is another matter. I would advise you use a `CursorLoader` of some flavor, but as you are already waiting for your query to return synchronously you might find an `ArrayAdapter` a simpler alternative.

```
         ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
          android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values);
        // Assign adapter to ListView
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Where `values` may have been populated by iterating through your `Cursor`:

```
while (res.moveToNext()) {
    values.add(new String(
            "Name: " + res.getString(1) + "\n" + "Age: " +
            res.getString(2) + "\n" + "Gender: " + res.getString(3) + "\n\n");
}
```

This assuming `values` is an `ArrayList<String>` in which case you probably could benefit from reading https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-an-ArrayAdapter-with-ListView

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to populate the same TextView multiple times. So the last result from your cursor will be set to your TextView.
I'd recommend creating a ListView and populating it with an Adapter, and then setting the row items within the adapter.

Comment: thanks so much for your quick response! I'll take a look into ListView now